# Tracking Page Popularity in a Time Frame in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tracking

I'm very new to web development and this seems like a basic question, so perhaps I just lack the correct terminology to search it on Google.

On my site I plan to have many dynamically generated pages, based off data in a MySQL server, and I would like to know which ones people have been visiting the most, in say, the last 24 hours, so that I can place these most popular page on the front page of the site. How would I/would I be able to accomplish this in a Rails application.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a *web analytics solution* to analyze your traffic, and possibly your marketing effectiveness. Here are some of the most prominent services you could use with your website:

- [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/)
- [Chartbeat](http://chartbeat.com/)
- [Reinvigorate](http://www.reinvigorate.net/)
- [HaveAMint](http://www.haveamint.com/)
- [GetClicky](http://www.getclicky.com/)
- [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)
- [Woopra](http://www.woopra.com/)

Personally, I use Google Analytics as its setup is darn simple: configure your account, add a Javascript snippet on each of the pages you want to track, and you're done.

You could also look out for web analytics software that *you* would host. All in all, take a look at [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software) for more information.